# Django users and authentication from external source

Tags: database, django, authentication

I have a Django app that gets it's data completely from an external source (queried via HTTP). That is, I don't have the option for a local database. Session data is stored in the cache (on my development server I use a SQLite database, so that is no error source). I'm using bleeding edge Django 1.1svn.

Enter the problem: I want to use Django's own authentication system for the users.

It seems quite simple to write my own Authentication Backend, but always just under the condition that you have a local database where to save the users. Without database my main problem is persistence.

I tried it with the following (assume that `datasource.get()` is a function that returns some kind of dict):

```
class ModelBackend (object):
    """Login backend."""

    def authenticate (self, username=None, password=None):
        """Check, if a given user/password combination is valid"""

        data = datasource.get ('login', username, password)
        if data and data['ok']:
            return MyUser (username=username)
        else:
            raise TypeError
            return None

    def get_user (self, username):
        """get data about a specific user"""

        try:
          data = datasource.get ('userdata', username)
          if data and data['ok']:
              return data.user
        except:
            pass
        return None


class MyUser (User):
    """Django user who isn't saved in DB"""

    def save (self):
        return None
```

But the intentionally missing `save()` method on MyUser seems to break the session storage of a login.

How should `MyUser` look like without a local database?

Comment: I just found <http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/auth-remote-user/>
Seems to do what I want. If I've evaluated it, I'll post an answer (don't be discouraged to add your own ;-) ).

Comment: The link has an ill-going trailing '>'... darn.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

OK, it's much more complicated than I thought. First, start with http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/auth-remote-user/, but you'll need to extend it with your own backend and user.

```
from django.contrib.auth.backends import RemoteUserBackend

class MyRemoteUserBackend (RemoteUserBackend):
    # Create a User object if not already in the database?
    create_unknown_user = False

    def get_user (self, user_id):
        user = somehow_create_an_instance_of (MyUser, user_id)
        return user

    def authenticate (self, **credentials):
        check_credentials ()
        user = somehow_create_an_instance_of (MyUser, credentials)
        return user
```

Then the user:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class MyUser (User):

    def save (self):
        """saving to DB disabled"""
        pass

    objects = None # we cannot really use this w/o local DB

    username = ""  # and all the other properties likewise.
                   # They're defined as model.CharField or similar,
                   # and we can't allow that

    def get_group_permissions (self):
        """If you don't make your own permissions module,
           the default also will use the DB. Throw it away"""
        return [] # likewise with the other permission defs

    def get_and_delete_messages (self):
        """Messages are stored in the DB. Darn!"""
        return []
```

Phew! Django **really** isn't designed for usage without a database...

Comment: what did you have to change in your settings file? I am trying to do this and it's like it's completely ignoring my remote backend.

Comment: Have you set something along `AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
'myapp.MyappUserBackend',
)`?

Comment: Yes. I figured it out, I needed to extend the remote auth middleware in my case because I was passing the credentials differently than the default.

Answer (score 5):

Rather than overwriting the `save` method, you may also disconnect the signal that invokes it. This is what I do in some apps which have read-only access to the user database.

```
# models.py (for instance)
from django.contrib.auth.models import update_last_login, user_logged_in
user_logged_in.disconnect(update_last_login)
```

Comment: I'm working with Django 1.6 and OP + this saved my day! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

`grep`ping the source showed, that the only place `user.save()` is actually called (except for user creation and password management code, which you don't need to use at all) is `django.contrib.auth.login()`, to update `user.last_login` value.

```
# TODO: It would be nice to support different login methods, like signed cookies.
user.last_login = datetime.datetime.now()
user.save()
```

If you don't want user data to rest in DB, try adding dummy `save()` method. If I'm right, it should work.

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    pass
```

Of course, because you have no persistence at all, you should consider caching `datasource.get` results, otherwise in worst case you may end up querying data again and again on every single logged in user's hit.