# Django & custom auth backend (web service) + no database. How to save stuff in session?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I've been searching here and there, and based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1057149/django-users-and-authentication-from-external-source/1073878#1073878) I've put together what you see below.
It works, but I need to put some stuff in the user's session, right there inside `authenticate`.

How would I store `acme_token` in the user's session, so that it will get cleared if they logged out? The `request` object is not available in this context

```
class AcmeUserBackend(object):
    # Create a User object if not already in the database?
    create_unknown_user = False

    def get_user(self, username):
        return AcmeUser(id=username)

    def authenticate(self, username=None, password=None):
        """ Check the username/password and return an AcmeUser. """
        acme_token = ask_another_site_about_creds(username, password)

        if acme_token:
            return AcmeUser(id=username)
        return None
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shove it onto [the returned user](http://bzr.fedorahosted.org/bzr/python-fedora/python-fedora-devel/annotate/head%3A/fedora/django/auth/backends.py), then [handle it in middleware](http://bzr.fedorahosted.org/bzr/python-fedora/python-fedora-devel/annotate/head%3A/fedora/django/auth/middleware.py).