# Django : Calling the authenticate method of a class that inherits from RemoteUserBackend

Tags: python, django, authentication

I am currently having difficulty customizing Djangos authentication system.
In my scenario there is no database and authentication happens through a http request. There are no tables to read from or write from.

This [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1057149/django-users-and-authentication-from-external-source) here  deals pretty much with the same case I am dealing with however i do not understand how a user is being created in his example. I also read [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/auth-remote-user/) from django manual  regarding `REMOTE_USER` authentication.Coming back to the first link the user posted this code here.It consists of a backend and a user object

Backend - inherit from RemoteUserBackend

```
from django.contrib.auth.backends import RemoteUserBackend

class MyRemoteUserBackend (RemoteUserBackend):
    # Create a User object if not already in the database?
    create_unknown_user = False

    def get_user (self, user_id):
        user = somehow_create_an_instance_of (MyUser, user_id)    ---->A
        return user

    def authenticate (self, **credentials):
        check_credentials ()
        user = somehow_create_an_instance_of (MyUser, credentials) ---->B
        return user
```

Then the user:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class MyUser (User):

    def save (self):
        """saving to DB disabled"""
        pass

    objects = None # we cannot really use this w/o local DB

    username = ""  # and all the other properties likewise.
                   # They're defined as model.CharField or similar,
                   # and we can't allow that

    def get_group_permissions (self):
        """If you don't make your own permissions module,
           the default also will use the DB. Throw it away"""
        return [] # likewise with the other permission defs

    def get_and_delete_messages (self):
        """Messages are stored in the DB. Darn!"""
        return []
```

Now my question is I would like to do something like this in my view

```
def my_view(request):
    username = request.POST['username']
    password = request.POST['password']
    user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
    if user is not None:
        if user.is_active:
            login(request, user)
```

Now how can I have `authenticate` method from `MyRemoteUserBackend` be called in the above code snippet and what does the snippet mean by `somehow_create_an_instance_of` any suggestions on this would be great