# Django: ValidationError using is_authenticated and logout when authenticating from an external source

Tags: python, django

I am currently building a Django application that gets all its data from an external source (via HTTP). I therefore do not want to use my own database. I have already implemented my own user and remote user backend as per the solution stated in this SO question: [Django users and authentication from external source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1057149/django-users-and-authentication-from-external-source). I am using signed cookies for storing sessions.

After implementing the above stated, I was able to login without any errors. However, on checking whether a user is authenticated in a template (or when trying to log him out in a view), I receive an error:

```
ValidationError at /products/
["'None' value must be an integer."]
```

at the line in the template

```
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
```

where request.user is passed as a template variable user in the corresponding view (I know I shouldn't do that, it's just temporary).

Here is some of the other relevant traceback:

```
/home/ines/.virtualenvs/diet/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/middleware.py in <lambda>
request.user = SimpleLazyObject(lambda: get_user(request))
 ...
/home/ines/.virtualenvs/diet/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/middleware.py in get_user
request._cached_user = auth.get_user(request)
 ...
/home/ines/.virtualenvs/diet/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/__init__.py in get_user
user_id = _get_user_session_key(request)
 ...
/home/ines/.virtualenvs/diet/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/__init__.py in _get_user_session_key
return get_user_model()._meta.pk.to_python(request.session[SESSION_KEY])
```

The error happens in the `to_python()` call, where the line 942 in file django/db/models/fields/__init__.py: `return int(value)` throws an Exception as it receives `value='None'`.

Let me now post all (hopefully) relevant code from my app.

**settings.py**

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = ('products.backends.ApiAuthBackend',)
```

**products/backends.py**

```
from django.contrib.auth.backends import RemoteUserBackend
from products.api import API
from products.models import ApiUser

class ApiAuthBackend(RemoteUserBackend):
    """
    Authenticate against the API.
    """

    create_unknown_user = False  # does not create a User object if it is not in the database

    def authenticate(self, request, username=None, password=None):
        api = API()
        access_token = api.login(username=username, password=password)
        if api.logged_in():
            user = ApiUser()
            user.username = username
            request.session['access_token'] = access_token
            return user
        return None

    def get_user(self, user_id):
        return ApiUser(username=user_id)
```

**products/models.py**

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

class ApiUser(AbstractUser):
    def save(self, **kwargs):
        """
        Disables saving to database.
        """
        pass

    objects = None
    username = ''
    first_name = ''
    last_name = ''
    email = ''
    password = ''
    groups = ''
    user_permissions = ''
    is_staff = False
    is_active = True
    is_superuser = False
    last_login = None
    date_joined = None

    def get_group_permissions(self, obj=None):
        return []

    def get_all_permissions(self, obj=None):
        return []

    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        return []

    def has_perms(self, obj=None, **kwargs):
        return []

    def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
        return []
```

Upon further inspection of the django/contrib/auth/__init__.py, line 154:

```
request.session[SESSION_KEY] = user._meta.pk.value_to_string(user)
```

The problem seems to be that the `request.session[SESSION_KEY]`, where `SESSION_KEY = '_auth_user_id'`, is set to `'None'`. That's due to the fact that the ApiUser class does not have Fields for attributes anymore - I have overriden them in models.py since I am not using a database. Therefore my instances of ApiUser do not have a pk, and SESSION_KEY attribute is therefore set to `'None'`. When Django wants to authenticate, the SESSION_KEY attribute of the session gets passed to the aforementioned `to_python()` function which in turn raises an Exception.

My question is, how do I fix this? I tried setting the user.pk to always be 1 and setting the `session[SESSION_KEY]` manually to 1 in the authenticate function in models.py, which has resulted in me not getting an exception but other data written to the session (access_token) has disappeared.

Thank you in advance for your time and answers, and I'm terribly sorry if there happens to be a solution to this somewhere already (I did search extensively but haven't been able to find it).

*Update (as per request by Bear Brown):*

Here is my code for API class, not sure it's really relevant as it's just used to communicate with the external database but anyway.

**products/api.py**

```
import requests
import json

class API:
    URL = "[...]" 
    KEY = "[...]"

    LOGIN = "authenticate/access-token"
    REGISTER = "authenticate/register"

    session = None
    debug = True

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        if len(kwargs) > 2 or not kwargs:
            return
        try:
            self.login(**kwargs)
        except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError:
            print("Could not connect to the database.")
        except requests.exceptions.RequestException:
            print("Could not retrieve data from the database.")

    def login(self, **kwargs):
        if self.session is not None:
            return
        assert 0 < len(kwargs) < 3
        access_token = ''
        if len(kwargs) == 2:
            username, password = kwargs['username'], kwargs['password']
            url = self.URL + self.LOGIN
            user_data = {
                'username': username,
                'password': password,
                'active-check': 0,
                'api_key':  self.KEY
            }
            r = requests.post(url, data=user_data)
            r.raise_for_status()
            response = r.json()
            if response['success'] is True:
                access_token = response['access_token']
        else:  # len(kwargs) == 1
            access_token = kwargs['access_token']

        if access_token:
            self.session = requests.Session()
            self.session.headers.update({'Authorization': 'Client-ID ' + access_token})
            if self.debug: print("Successfully logged in.")

        return access_token

    def logout(self):
        if self.session is None:
            return
        self.session.close()
        self.session = None

    def logged_in(self):
        return self.session is not None
```

Here is a link to the full error traceback on pastebin (it seemed too be too long to add to an already long post):
[full error traceback on pastebin](https://pastebin.com/b2V48KxT).

Answer (score 0):

I'm in a similar situation and seeing this error. For me the solution was to provide a value for the `id` attribute of the custom `User` class when creating the user object.

This allows the default `login()` function to work as it provides the value for the required primary key attribute.

My backend now looks something like this:

```py
class CustomBackend(BaseBackend):
    def get_user(self, user_id):
        user = [...] # API call to get user data

        return CTUser(
            id=user_id, # <- added this
            username=user['cmsUserId'],
            email=user['email'],
            first_name=user['firstName'],
            last_name=user['lastName'],
        )

    def authenticate(self, request, username=None, password=None, **kwargs):
        userid = [...] # API call to authenticate and get user id

        user = self.get_user(userid)
        user.logintoken = password

        return user
```